# PrimeNG overlay panel delay

Tags: angular, events, primeng

I am experencing a strange issue in which the [PrimeNG OverlayPanel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/overlaypanel) is not appearing on button click, but it appears if I set breakpoint in the `click` event and most bazarly it appears if I trigger a click event on any other element or resize the view.
Here is the GIF of my screen to show you what's happening:
As you can see I click on the button and nothing happens, only when I trigger the other events.

[image: Prime NG OverlayPanel delay]

Here is my HTML:

```
<button pButton class="button is-rounded is-primary" (click)="rotation($event)">
  Rotation
</button>

<p-overlayPanel #rotationPopup [showCloseIcon]="true" appendTo="body" >
  <rotation-editor></rotation-editor>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

And my TS:

```
    @ViewChild('rotationPopup', { static: false }) rotationPopup: OverlayPanel;

    constructor(...) {}

    rotation(event) {
      let isVisible = this.rotationPopup.visible;
      if (isVisible) {
        this.rotationPopup.hide();
      } else {
        this.rotationPopup.show(event);
      }
```

Any help.
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but I also experience same kind of issue, I think its related to change detection cycle of Angular, When overlay panel shows up, UI is not updating. Try using manual change detection in this case.

Comment: We had a similar issue and tried using manual change detection. The main problem for us is that we are receiving the event *before* the OverlayPanel calls markForCheck, so calling detectChanges is having no effect